# Adding list element to unordered list giving error

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

To add li element in ul I have done this...

```
var ul = document.getElementById('ul-id');
var li= document.createElement("li");
li.appendChild("some text here");
ul.appendChild(li);
```

But its giving error in my console. I am not getting what is the problem with this code. Any help will be appreciated.

Error:

```
Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8
code: 8
message: "NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8"
name: "NotFoundError"
stack: "Error: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `appendChild()` expects a dom element reference as the parameter. You are passing a string as the value to the `appendChild()`, instead pass a text node

`li.appendChild("some text here");` should be

```
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("some text here"));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Dp8s3/)

or

```
li.innerHTML = "some text here2";
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vCLqk/)